# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null. In chrome app development

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am making an app for the Chrome Web Store. It is a clone of the Doodle Jump game. When I test and load it as an unpacked extension, this error keeps coming up.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
```

My code is here:
Javascript

```js
function startGame() {
 // RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
 window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback) {
   window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
 })();

 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var width = 422,
  height = 552;

 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;

 //Variables for game
 var platforms = [],
  image = document.getElementById("sprite"),
  player, platformCount = 10,
  position = 0,
  gravity = 0.2,
  animloop,
  flag = 0,
  menuloop, broken = 0,
  dir, score = 0, firstRun = true;

 //Base object
 var Base = function() {
  this.height = 5;
  this.width = width;

  //Sprite clipping
  this.cx = 0;
  this.cy = 614;
  this.cwidth = 100;
  this.cheight = 5;

  this.moved = 0;

  this.x = 0;
  this.y = height - this.height;

  this.draw = function() {
   try {
    ctx.drawImage(image, this.cx, this.cy, this.cwidth, this.cheight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
   } catch (e) {}
  };
 };

 var base = new Base();

 //Player object
 var Player = function() {
  this.vy = 11;
  this.vx = 0;

  this.isMovingLeft = false;
  this.isMovingRight = false;
  this.isDead = false;

  this.width = 55;
  this.height = 40;

  //Sprite clipping
  this.cx = 0;
  this.cy = 0;
  this.cwidth = 110;
  this.cheight = 80;

  this.dir = "left";

  this.x = width / 2 - this.width / 2;
  this.y = height;

  //Function to draw it
  this.draw = function() {
   try {
    if (this.dir == "right") this.cy = 121;
    else if (this.dir == "left") this.cy = 201;
    else if (this.dir == "right_land") this.cy = 289;
    else if (this.dir == "left_land") this.cy = 371;

    ctx.drawImage(image, this.cx, this.cy, this.cwidth, this.cheight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
   } catch (e) {}
  };

  this.jump = function() {
   this.vy = -8;
   document.getElementById('audio').innerHTML='<audio src="sounds/pup.mp3" preload="auto" autoplay autobuffer></audio>'
  };

  this.jumpHigh = function() {
   this.vy = -16;
   document.getElementById('audio').innerHTML='<audio src="sounds/high.mp3" preload="auto" autoplay autobuffer></audio>'
  };

 };

 player = new Player();

 //Platform class

 function Platform() {
  this.width = 70;
  this.height = 17;

  this.x = Math.random() * (width - this.width);
  this.y = position;

  position += (height / platformCount);

  this.flag = 0;
  this.state = 0;

  //Sprite clipping
  this.cx = 0;
  this.cy = 0;
  this.cwidth = 105;
  this.cheight = 31;

  //Function to draw it
  this.draw = function() {
   try {

    if (this.type == 1) this.cy = 0;
    else if (this.type == 2) this.cy = 61;
    else if (this.type == 3 && this.flag === 0) this.cy = 31;
    else if (this.type == 3 && this.flag == 1) this.cy = 1000;
    else if (this.type == 4 && this.state === 0) this.cy = 90;
    else if (this.type == 4 && this.state == 1) this.cy = 1000;

    ctx.drawImage(image, this.cx, this.cy, this.cwidth, this.cheight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
   } catch (e) {}
  };

  //Platform types
  //1: Normal
  //2: Moving
  //3: Breakable (Go through)
  //4: Vanishable
  //Setting the probability of which type of platforms should be shown at what score
  if (score >= 5000) this.types = [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];
  else if (score >= 2000 && score < 5000) this.types = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];
  else if (score >= 1000 && score < 2000) this.types = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
  else if (score >= 500 && score < 1000) this.types = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3];
  else if (score >= 100 && score < 500) this.types = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2];
  else this.types = [1];

  this.type = this.types[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.types.length)];

  //We can't have two consecutive breakable platforms otherwise it will be impossible to reach another platform sometimes!
  if (this.type == 3 && broken < 1) {
   broken++;
  } else if (this.type == 3 && broken >= 1) {
   this.type = 1;
   broken = 0;
  }

  this.moved = 0;
  this.vx = 1;
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < platformCount; i++) {
  platforms.push(new Platform());
 }

 //Broken platform object
 var Platform_broken_substitute = function() {
  this.height = 30;
  this.width = 70;

  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  //Sprite clipping
  this.cx = 0;
  this.cy = 554;
  this.cwidth = 105;
  this.cheight = 60;

  this.appearance = false;

  this.draw = function() {
   try {
    if (this.appearance === true) ctx.drawImage(image, this.cx, this.cy, this.cwidth, this.cheight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    else return;
   } catch (e) {}
  };
 };

 var platform_broken_substitute = new Platform_broken_substitute();

 //Spring Class
 var spring = function() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.width = 26;
  this.height = 30;

  //Sprite clipping
  this.cx = 0;
  this.cy = 0;
  this.cwidth = 45;
  this.cheight = 53;

  this.state = 0;

  this.draw = function() {
   try {
    if (this.state === 0) this.cy = 445;
    else if (this.state == 1) this.cy = 501;

    ctx.drawImage(image, this.cx, this.cy, this.cwidth, this.cheight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
   } catch (e) {}
  };
 };

 var Spring = new spring();

 function init() {
  //Variables for the game
  var dir = "left",
   jumpCount = 0;

  firstRun = false;

  //Function for clearing canvas in each consecutive frame

  function paintCanvas() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  //Player related calculations and functions

  function playerCalc() {
   if (dir == "left") {
    player.dir = "left";
    if (player.vy < -7 && player.vy > -15) player.dir = "left_land";
   } else if (dir == "right") {
    player.dir = "right";
    if (player.vy < -7 && player.vy > -15) player.dir = "right_land";
   }

   //Adding keyboard controls
   document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;

    if (key == 37) {
     dir = "left";
     player.isMovingLeft = true;
    } else if (key == 39) {
     dir = "right";
     player.isMovingRight = true;
    }

    if(key == 32) {
     if(firstRun === true)
      init();
     else
      reset();
    }
   };

   document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;

    if (key == 37) {
     dir = "left";
     player.isMovingLeft = false;
    } else if (key == 39) {
     dir = "right";
     player.isMovingRight = false;
    }
   };

   //Accelerations produces when the user hold the keys
   if (player.isMovingLeft === true) {
    player.x += player.vx;
    player.vx -= 0.15;
   } else {
    player.x += player.vx;
    if (player.vx < 0) player.vx += 0.1;
   }

   if (player.isMovingRight === true) {
    player.x += player.vx;
    player.vx += 0.15;
   } else {
    player.x += player.vx;
    if (player.vx > 0) player.vx -= 0.1;
   }

   //Jump the player when it hits the base
   if ((player.y + player.height) > base.y && base.y < height) player.jump();

   //Gameover if it hits the bottom
   if (base.y > height && (player.y + player.height) > height && player.isDead != "lol") {
 player.isDead = true;
 document.getElementById('audio').innerHTML='<audio src="sounds/gameover.mp3" preload="auto" autoplay autobuffer></audio>'
 }

   //Make the player move through walls
   if (player.x > width) player.x = 0 - player.width;
   else if (player.x < 0 - player.width) player.x = width;

   //Movement of player affected by gravity
   if (player.y >= (height / 2) - (player.height / 2)) {
    player.y += player.vy;
    player.vy += gravity;
   }

   //When the player reaches half height, move the platforms to create the illusion of scrolling and recreate the platforms that are out of viewport...
   else {
    platforms.forEach(function(p, i) {

     if (player.vy < 0) {
      p.y -= player.vy;
     }

     if (p.y > height) {
      platforms[i] = new Platform();
      platforms[i].y = p.y - height;
     }

    });

    base.y -= player.vy;
    player.vy += gravity;

    if (player.vy >= 0) {
     player.y += player.vy;
     player.vy += gravity;
    }

    score++;
   }

   //Make the player jump when it collides with platforms
   collides();

   if (player.isDead === true) gameOver();
  }

  //Spring algorithms

  function springCalc() {
   var s = Spring;
   var p = platforms[0];

   if (p.type == 1 || p.type == 2) {
    s.x = p.x + p.width / 2 - s.width / 2;
    s.y = p.y - p.height - 10;

    if (s.y > height / 1.1) s.state = 0;

    s.draw();
   } else {
    s.x = 0 - s.width;
    s.y = 0 - s.height;
   }
  }

  //Platform's horizontal movement (and falling) algo

  function platformCalc() {
   var subs = platform_broken_substitute;

   platforms.forEach(function(p, i) {
    if (p.type == 2) {
     if (p.x < 0 || p.x + p.width > width) p.vx *= -1;

     p.x += p.vx;
    }

    if (p.flag == 1 && subs.appearance === false && jumpCount === 0) {
     subs.x = p.x;
     subs.y = p.y;
     subs.appearance = true;

     jumpCount++;
    }

    p.draw();
   });

   if (subs.appearance === true) {
    subs.draw();
    subs.y += 8;
   }

   if (subs.y > height) subs.appearance = false;
  }

  function collides() {
   //Platforms
   platforms.forEach(function(p, i) {
    if (player.vy > 0 && p.state === 0 && (player.x + 15 < p.x + p.width) && (player.x + player.width - 15 > p.x) && (player.y + player.height > p.y) && (player.y + player.height < p.y + p.height)) {

     if (p.type == 3 && p.flag === 0) {
      p.flag = 1;
      jumpCount = 0;
      return;
     } else if (p.type == 4 && p.state === 0) {
      player.jump();
      p.state = 1;
     } else if (p.flag == 1) return;
     else {
      player.jump();
     }
    }
   });

   //Springs
   var s = Spring;
   if (player.vy > 0 && (s.state === 0) && (player.x + 15 < s.x + s.width) && (player.x + player.width - 15 > s.x) && (player.y + player.height > s.y) && (player.y + player.height < s.y + s.height)) {
    s.state = 1;
    player.jumpHigh();
   }

  }

  function updateScore() {
   var scoreText = document.getElementById("score");
   scoreText.innerHTML = score;
  }

  function gameOver() {

   platforms.forEach(function(p, i) {
    p.y -= 12;
   });

   if(player.y > height/2 && flag === 0) {
    player.y -= 8;
    player.vy = 0;
   }
   else if(player.y < height / 2) flag = 1;
   else if(player.y + player.height > height) {
    showGoMenu();
    hideScore();
    player.isDead = "lol";

   }
  }

  //Function to update everything

  function update() {
   paintCanvas();
   platformCalc();

   springCalc();

   playerCalc();
   player.draw();

   base.draw();

   updateScore();
  }

  menuLoop = function(){return;};
  animloop = function() {
   update();
   requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  };

  animloop();

  hideMenu();
  showScore();
 }

 function reset() {
  hideGoMenu();
  showScore();
  player.isDead = false;

  flag = 0;
  position = 0;
  score = 0;

  base = new Base();
  player = new Player();
  Spring = new spring();
  platform_broken_substitute = new Platform_broken_substitute();

  platforms = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < platformCount; i++) {
   platforms.push(new Platform());
  }
 }

 //Hides the menu
 function hideMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("mainMenu");
  menu.style.zIndex = -1;
 }

 //Shows the game over menu
 function showGoMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("gameOverMenu");
  menu.style.zIndex = 1;
  menu.style.visibility = "visible";

  var scoreText = document.getElementById("go_score");
  scoreText.innerHTML = "Р’Р°С€ СЂРµР·СѓР»СЊС‚Р°С‚ " + score + " РѕС‡РєРѕРІ!";
 }

 //Hides the game over menu
 function hideGoMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("gameOverMenu");
  menu.style.zIndex = -1;
  menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
 }

 //Show ScoreBoard
 function showScore() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("scoreBoard");
  menu.style.zIndex = 1;
 }

 //Hide ScoreBoard
 function hideScore() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("scoreBoard");
  menu.style.zIndex = -1;
 }

 function playerJump() {
  player.y += player.vy;
  player.vy += gravity;

  if (player.vy > 0 &&
   (player.x + 15 < 260) &&
   (player.x + player.width - 15 > 155) &&
   (player.y + player.height > 475) &&
   (player.y + player.height < 500))
   player.jump();

  if (dir == "left") {
   player.dir = "left";
   if (player.vy < -7 && player.vy > -15) player.dir = "left_land";
  } else if (dir == "right") {
   player.dir = "right";
   if (player.vy < -7 && player.vy > -15) player.dir = "right_land";
  }

  //Adding keyboard controls
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode;

   if (key == 37) {
    dir = "left";
    player.isMovingLeft = true;
   } else if (key == 39) {
    dir = "right";
    player.isMovingRight = true;
   }

   if(key == 32) {
    if(firstRun === true) {
     init();
     firstRun = false;
    }
    else
     reset();
   }
  };

  document.onkeyup = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode;

   if (key == 37) {
    dir = "left";
    player.isMovingLeft = false;
   } else if (key == 39) {
    dir = "right";
    player.isMovingRight = false;
   }
  };

  //Accelerations produces when the user hold the keys
  if (player.isMovingLeft === true) {
   player.x += player.vx;
   player.vx -= 0.15;
  } else {
   player.x += player.vx;
   if (player.vx < 0) player.vx += 0.1;
  }

  if (player.isMovingRight === true) {
   player.x += player.vx;
   player.vx += 0.15;
  } else {
   player.x += player.vx;
   if (player.vx > 0) player.vx -= 0.1;
  }

  //Jump the player when it hits the base
  if ((player.y + player.height) > base.y && base.y < height) player.jump();

  //Make the player move through walls
  if (player.x > width) player.x = 0 - player.width;
  else if (player.x < 0 - player.width) player.x = width;

  player.draw();
 }

 function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  playerJump();
 }

 menuLoop = function() {
  update();
  requestAnimFrame(menuLoop);
 };

 menuLoop();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startGame, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Doodle Jump</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(Gloria%20Hallelujah);

*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
 margin: 0; padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
}

.container {
 height: 552px;
 width: 422px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
 height: 552px;
 width: 422px;
 display: block;
 background: url(images/Y0BMP.png) top left;
}

#scoreBoard {
 width: 420px;
 height: 50px;
 background: rgba(182, 200, 220, 0.7);
 position: absolute;
 top: -3px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 border-image: url(images/5BBsR.png) 100 5 round;
}

#scoreBoard p {
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 47px;
 margin: 0px 0 0 5px;
}

img {display: none}

#mainMenu, #gameOverMenu {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
}

#gameOverMenu {
 visibility: hidden;
}

h2, h3, h1 {font-weight: normal}
h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 color: #5a5816;
 transform: rotate(-10deg);
 margin: 0px;
}

h3 {text-align: right; margin: -10px 20px 0 0; color: #5e96be}
h3 a {color: #5a5816}

.button {
 width: 105px;
 height: 31px;
 background: url(images/2WEhF.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
 display: block;
 color:  #000;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 31px;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 50px;
 margin-left: -53px;
}

.info {position: absolute; right: 20px; bottom: 00px; margin: 0; color: green}

.info .key {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 background: url(images/2WEhF.png) no-repeat;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.info .key.left {background-position: -92px -621px;}
.info .key.right {background-position: -92px -641px;}
</style>
</head>
<body><div style="position:absolute;z-index:999;padding:10px;top:0;right:0;background:#000" id="sxz03">
<div style="float:right;padding-left:10px"><img onclick="document.getElementById('sxz03').style.display='none'" src="images/x.gif" width="15" alt="" /></div>
<br>
<div style="position:absolute;top:-100px"></div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <div id="mainMenu">
   <h1>doodle jump</h1>
   <h3>A HTML5 game</h3>
   <a class="button" href="javascript:init()">Play</a>
  </div>

  <div id="gameOverMenu">
   <h1>Game Over!</h1>
   <h3 id="go_score">Your score was ...</h3>

   <a class="button" href="javascript:reset()">Play Again</a>

  </div>


  <!-- Preloading image ;) -->
  <img id="sprite" src="images/2WEhF.png"/>

  <div id="scoreBoard">
   <p id="score">0</p>
  </div>



 </div>

<div id="audio"></div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I run this, the intro works, but when I click the play button, nothing happens. If you want to run this code, I will put a download link for the folder that I used in this question.

Comment: [Have a look in the console](https://jsfiddle.net/8rwm93ht/). The error is "`init` is not defined". `init` is nested inside the `startGame` function and it cannot be accessed. You need to have another think about your code design.

Comment: Assuming the game is inside the extension popup, you probably run game.js also as a content script, which is a mistake. Note, the [popup has its own devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982).

Comment: In my manifest file, I have game.js as a background script